# Windows netsh TCP portproxy fails to forward packets through loopback, solutions?

Tags: windows-7, networking, proxy, firewall, ipv6

Here is the situation, running Win 7 Pro SP1 (Version 6.1.7601), Windows firewall is completely disabled (even added rules to allow anything through just in case somehow it's still going), no programs running in background (killed off every needless service/exe), ipv6 is installed and working fine, netsh isatap and 6to4 are enabled. Teredo is set to the default state.

First, I can setup a netsh v4tov4 portproxy to the 192/8 interface and in this situation the portproxy will work fine. In two elevated command shells I run:

```
REM Admin Shell 1
ncat.exe -l 192.168.2.173 13337

REM Admin Shell 2
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=18080 connectport=13337 connectaddress=192.168.2.173
netsh interface portproxy show all

    Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:

    Address         Port        Address         Port
    --------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
    *               18080       192.168.2.173   13337

ncat 192.168.2.173 18080
[type a message and it will popup in shell 1]

C:\temp>netstat -a -b | grep -E -A1 13337
  TCP    192.168.2.173:13337     Windows7_x64:0         LISTENING
 [ncat.exe]
```

The port proxy forwards and netcat works as expected.

Next, simply changing to localhost (which resolves to [::1]) or explicitly using 127.0.0.1 with a v4tov4 rule (also tried v6tov4) fails every time.

For example, starting with 127.0.0.1

```
REM Admin Shell 1
ncat.exe -l 127.0.0.1 13337

REM Admin Shell 2
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=18080 connectport=13337 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
netsh interface portproxy show all

    Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:

    Address         Port        Address         Port
    --------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
    *               18080       127.0.0.1       13337

ncat 127.0.0.1 18080
Ncat: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. .

C:\temp>netstat -a -b | grep -E -A1 13337
  TCP    127.0.0.1:13337         Windows7_x64:0         LISTENING
  [ncat.exe]
```

Finally, deleting all old netsh rules, and trying it with v6tov6 is also a complete bomb:

```
REM Admin Shell 1
ncat.exe -6 -l [::1] 13337

REM Admin Shell 2
netsh interface portproxy add v6tov6 listenport=18080 connectport=13337 connectaddress=[::1]
netsh interface portproxy show all

    Listen on ipv6:             Connect to ipv6:

    Address         Port        Address         Port
    --------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
    *               18080       [::1]           13337

ncat -6 [::1] 18080
Ncat: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

C:\temp>netstat -a -b | grep -E -A1 13337
  TCP    [::1]:13337             Windows7_x64:0         LISTENING
  [ncat.exe]
```

Note Windows7_x64 is localhost and the interface appears to be working fine.

```
C:\>ping localhost
Pinging Windows7_x64 [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

Also I can directly connect to the listening netcat endpoint and send data without any issues:

```
ncat -6 [::1] 13337
```

The problem is definitely with the netsh portproxy rules.

So what gives here? Firewall is completely off. Elevated shell. Nothing else running to get in the way (no AV/IDS).

I tried adding various combinations of v6tov4 and v4tov6 rules, but that hasn't done anything either. MS Message Analyzer isn't helping because it's not picking up the localhost interface even when the connection does establish.

Any ideas?

**Edit 2016/10/15 23:58EST:**
Stopping the following six services disables portproxying across the board. That would suggest one of these services is involved with what's happening.

```
sc stop homegrouplistener
sc stop Browser
sc stop lanmanserver
sc stop smb
sc stop iphlpsvc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Packets arriving on the loopback interface (which does not really exist on Windows) cannot originate from anything but `127.0.0.0/8`. Likewise, you cannot send packets to anything but `127.0.0.0/8` because there is no route to other locations. That means even if the traffic would arrive, the listening program couldn’t answer.

If you use a proxy program, it takes traffic from the external network and produces *new* traffic on the loopback interface (and vice-versa). This will work.

Consider the following (OS X) nmap example:

```
sudo nmap -Pn -p 80 -S 192.168.2.1 -e lo0 127.0.0.1
```

It will forcibly (via root) inject packets into the loopback interface. This can be verified by running `tcpdump -i lo0` on another terminal. However, even when `nc` was listening, it wouldn’t find the open port. The following however finds the listener as expected:

```
nmap -p 80 -e lo0 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This is still strange because all the netsh portproxy rule says is pass 127.0.0.1:18080 to 127.0.0.1:13337 on the same local interface. That fits the criteria of only transmitting across 127/8.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that part. Loopback networking doesn't work like regular networking. To speed things up, a lot of steps are skipped, which probably includes most firewall stuff (including port forwarding). Instead, data is directly copied to the target application's memory.

Comment: The ncat message suggests the netsh portproxy is hitting some service that's actively denying the connection: *"Ncat: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."* IPC/named pipes just means the OSI stack is skipped such that there is no need to add and then reverse the headers. If the interface was memory mapping we should see data writing out on the other end because the socket receiver is effectively a pointer waiting for a change in memory.

Comment: The ncat message does not indicate `netsh portproxy` is effective at all. In fact, I’d even say it hints at it not being effective. // I wrote copied, not mapped. The specifics depend on the OS.

Comment: Fair enough, the message could definitely be an unreachable condition WSAEHOSTUNREACH as easily as a WSAECONNREFUSED. I'll write a quick little socket program to see what error I get back on connect.